# Reading properties with multiple values in one line

Tags: java

I want to make a value in my config.properties for example like this:

```
blocked_names=Filon,Alron,Kren
```

or

```
blocked_names="Filon","Alron","Kren"
```

Every name will be read separately and it will be checked if the name is valid or not.
Here is line where name is checked but it works only if one name is added

```
if (nick.equals(config.getProperty("blocked_names"))){ 
                info_info.setText("This name is blocked!");
                return;
        }
```

Do you know how should I make this to work fine ?
Sorry for my English but I am still learning :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to split the value of `blocked_names` into an array of strings and then iterate the array.

Do it as follows:

```
String [] blockedNames = config.getProperty("blocked_names").split(",");
for(String name: blockedNames) {
    if (nick.equals(name.replace("\"", ""))){// Remove " from name
        info_info.setText(name + " is blocked!");
        return;
    }
}
```